# Why does setting my MAC address take two attempts?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, zsh

I'm new to SE so I'm not sure if this is the correct site, but I am trying to change my MAC address to a fixed value on startup of macOS using zshell (bash should be similar or the same ).

I oddly found out that if I run this command once, it does not work, but if I run it twice in a row it works:

```
 3c:22:fb:3a:dc:14
 < /Users/c/top > sudo ifconfig en0 ether 3c:22:fb:3a:dc:15
 < /Users/c/top > mac
 3c:22:fb:3a:dc:14
 < /Users/c/top > sudo ifconfig en0 ether 3c:22:fb:3a:dc:15
 < /Users/c/top > sudo ifconfig en0 ether 3c:22:fb:3a:dc:15
 < /Users/c/top > mac
 3c:22:fb:3a:dc:15
 < /Users/c/top >
```

mac is implemented as follows:

```
# shows the mac address
mac() {
  ifconfig en0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
}
```

More info.

```
SW - macOS version 11.6 - Big Sur
HW - MacBook Air
```

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running, on what hardware?

Comment: Also, what is `mac`?

Comment: `mac` could be shorthand for a `ifconfig en0 | grep 'ether' | awk '{print $2}' something something`  bobby wang created to extract just the MAC address instead of wading through all the `ifconfig` results.

Comment: Q updated to provide requested info.

Comment: What happens if you set the ifconfig and then wait a minute before checking it?